# Dygraph x-axis date not displaying

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

OK, I am totally baffled here.  I had this working but have done something to break dygraphs.  I am using dygraphs in multiple places - in some instances, I am graphing data that is not a function of time and some data that is a function of time.  In the case where data is *not* a function of time, the x-axis is properly displayed.

In the case where the data is plotted as a function of time, (i.e. the first entry of every array is a javascript `Date` object) the x-axis is totally neglected (i.e. there are no labels for the x-axis).  Currently, the `options` object looks like

```
vm.options = {
    ylabel: 'P (mb)',
    labels: ['t', 'Alicat0'],
    legend: 'always',
    axes: {
           y: {
               axisLabelWidth: 70
              },
           x: {
               drawAxis: true,
               axisLabelFormatter: function (d) {
                   return Dygraph.zeropad(d.getHours()) + ":" +    
                          Dygraph.zeropad(d.getMinutes()) + ":" +
                          Dygraph.zeropad(d.getSeconds());
                   }
             }
         },
         xlabel: "time"
};
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This should shed some light - the array containing the xticks (``layout.xticks``) is empty.  The dates are usually spaced by 1 second and as you can see above I am attempting to display only the time in hh:mm:ss format.

Comment: I suggest you inspect the value 'd' in the axisLabelFormatter to see what dygraph sends when it calls this function to format  the labels.
If that fails, try to post your code in jsfiddle or your actual html and full js code with data so we can see the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved.  Turns out that my array was backwards such that my largest value (most current time) was in the 0 position of the array.  Dygraphs did not like this.

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you. I spent 3 hours on this!